# Empty static prefix not permitted

Tags: django, python-2.7

I´m working with a tutorial on udemy. I´m at the part about setting up static files [image: on video 22, it shows how to configure static files]. 
https://www.udemy.com/probar-django-construir-una-aplicacion-web-en-python/learn/v4/overview that´s the link.

on video 22 it shows how to configure static files.

I configured everything as in the tutorial. this is a little further than just typing code from docs, colins, upper case 'POST'. Again, my code is exactly as in the tutorial.

any comment about how to read the error message and only look at the useful
stuff with be of good help as well.

the video is in Spanish but, the pages and the code are in English.

can anybody tell me from looking at the error message or taking a look at
the tutorial to see what could be wrong.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x034034B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in 
inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", 
self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\src\pd110\urls.py", line 32, in 
<module>
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "C:\Users\migel\Desktop\pd110\lib\site-
packages\django\conf\urls\static.py", line 24, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not 
permitted
```

my url.py

"""pd110 URL Configuration

```
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please 
see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

from boletin import views
#from boletin.views inicio

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^$', views.inicio, name='inicio'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
#/static/images/img1.jpg

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_pro", "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", 
"static_root")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", 
"media_root")
```

Comment: Have you set the `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: Yes. Could updating Jave have anything to do with thy error?

Comment: I don't think so. Could you show your `urls.py` please?

Comment: I added my url.py

Comment: And what are the `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` set to?

Comment: No, I mean the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the source and glance at [the function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/afc06b56256f78ab832ff8066ac6f34b7443de22/django/conf/urls/static.py#L21) raising that error, it starts:

```
# django/conf/urls/static.py
def static(prefix, view=serve, **kwargs):
    ...
    if not prefix:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
```

So at some point in your code, you're passing a false-y (like an empty-string) as the first argument `prefix`. Looking at your `urls.py`, you have

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I would guess that either the `STATIC_URL` or `MEDIA_URL` is empty. It looks like you declared former, so probably the latter.

Comment: If they are empty, they will cause the exact problem you asked.

Comment: Well, static looks properly configured. Just asking, where can I start looking for the empty (Y)?

Comment: What is properly configured...are you getting the same error? I explain *exactly* how the error in your question occurs, and it's the *only* way it can: **you are calling `static()` where your first argument evaluates to False**. I don't know this, because you haven't answered The_Cthulhu_Kid, but one of them is probably blank, and blank strings evaluate to False.

Answer (score 1):

url.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL,
        document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#/static/imagenes/img1.jpg

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_pro", "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", 
"static_root")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", 
"media_root")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hye!!! It seems like root media folder is not created, first create superuser and create the job,then the folder will be created automatically.
Then add media url "
+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)".

Hope! will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I read through the `static.py` file and it requires a prefix... so I did something like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

And I was up and running again with no errors...